# Alternator Synchronization in Smart Grid

Tags: power-engineering

Recently I was studying on the web that in the smart grid we need to synchronise the alternators. My beginner question is: Why do we need to synchronise alternators in a power system grid?

Comment: Start with this - What is the grid's waveform?

Comment: They need to be synchronized for *any* grid, not just 'smart' ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generators/alternators must be synchronized so that they can be placed in parallel on the grid to share the current load. If they were not frequency and phase synchronized, there would be substantial power loss from the generators "fighting" each other.

You can mathematically describe the problem by considering the sum of two cosine current sources with unequal phase angles.

Comment: If an unsynchronized generator is switched to the grid, the circuit breakers will disconnect it if there is a larger phase difference.